# How to store an image (e.g. profile picture) in localforage?

Tags: reactjs, localforage

I've a functionality of edit profile on my website in which I've to change profile picture. It gets changed but on page refresh, reverts back to old profile picture. In order to resolve this issue, I am trying to store it in localforage. Problem is, it does not get stored in localforage and on refresh, the picture reverts to the old one.
How can I properly store the image (or its URL, whichever is appropriate), in the localforage?

I've tried storing it like this:

```
const { profilePic } = this.props;
localforage.getItem('currentUser').then((currentUser) => {
  currentUser.profile_pic.url = profilePic;
  localforage.setItem('currentUser',currentUser);
});
```

where currentUser looks like as follows:

[image]

I want the newly uploaded image to get saved in localforage. Right now it is not getting stored in the localforage properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
const { profilePic } = this.props;
localforage.getItem('currentUser').then((currentUser) => {
   currentUser.profile_pic.url = profilePic;
   localforage.setItem('currentUser',currentUser).then(()=>{});
});
```

I have tried

```
localforage.getItem('somekey').then((value) => {
  // This code runs once the value has been loaded
  // from the offline store.
  localforage.setItem('somekey', 'some other value').then(()=>{

})

}).catch(function(err) {
  // This code runs if there were any errors
  console.log(err);
});
localforage.getItem('somekey').then(function(value) {
  // This code runs once the value has been loaded
  // from the offline store.
  console.log(value);
}).catch(function(err) {
  // This code runs if there were any errors
  console.log(err);
});
```

And this worked for me. :-)